# no internet connection after disconnected form cisco in terminal Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, vpn, cisco

when I disconnected from cisco vpn in terminal cant access to internet anymore until reboot the system

I also use

```
sudo service network-manager reload



sudo killall vpn



systemctl restart NetworkManager

sudo service network-manager restart
```

but don't work for me and I must reboot the system to connect internet again . .  .

Comment: compare routing table before running vpn and after with for example `ip route` command, also check `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: `killall vpn` likely overwrote your system's `/etc/resolv.conf` or changed your DNS configuration in resolved.  When you connect to the VPN, run `sudo resolvectl status` and check the DNS servers configured.  Then kill your VPN and run the same command and compare the data.  If your VPN connection reset your DNS then that's why you have no internet.  Also check the values of `ip -4 route list` before and after as well to see if it's leaving stale things in place.

Comment: I use expressvpn and they have had that same issue for about 9 months now. Their support told me that is simply the way their  software works. They did say it was after the change about 9 months ago to increase security.

Comment: Enter `ip route` to see your route table after disconnected from the vpn. If the default gateway has changed by your vpn, you can change it back to original one manually.